# Type safety when using requestUri of HttpClient.GetAsync(String) in Micro Services

Tags: wcf, service, asp.net-web-api, httpclient

In a micro-service architecture in .NET, there are many WebAPI services. They interact each other with Uri which are primarily strings.

```
HttpClient client = new HttpClient()
client.BaseAddress = new Uri("http://localhost:9000/");

HttpResponseMessage response = await client.GetAsync("api/products/1");
HttpResponseMessage response = await client.GetAsync("api/products");
```

The magic strings like **api/products/1** causes code maintainability problem - the magic strings are spread in the code. The consumer or the client application can break if there service changes in the *apicontroller* or the *action*. There is no proxy like WCF provides where the client can use type safe service calls.

How can I bring the type safety to webapi service calls?

Answer (score 2):

These micro services should not be coupled together and communicating directly with each other. One of the key points of micro services is to decouple so the services are not dependent on each other. This way one micro service can be taken down or updated and the rest of the micro services are not affected. If you use an [API Gateway](http://microservices.io/patterns/apigateway.html), this gateway is the only thing that would need to change if services change. If direct service-to-service communication is needed, I would use a messaging or queue service to facilitate this. Now each service could subscribe to what it needs from the other services without knowing what it's endpoints (or interfaces are). Only the gateway knows about the micro service's interfaces and can update if the interfaces are changed. Now the API Gateway is the only interface external clients need to know about. These interfaces can now have a versioning strategy and these interfaces are the only ones that are "public". No micro service interfaces should be public.

Comment: I agree with you on the fact that a gateway is required. In the gateway, there would be calls to many micro services (webapi) That's where I see the problem of type safety of those webapis as well as the gateway to break if a micro service changes. Versioning is good but still it does not solve the problem of type safety.

Comment: Each of your micro services could publish a nuget package (or manually distribute). This way as your micro services change, you can get those changes from the shared library. Only the gateway would use these shared libraries.

Comment: Are you suggesting, the gateway WebAPI app link with the micro-service WebAPI assembly and make calls to in-memory instances (var catalogController = new CatalogController()) instead of calling by URI (eg. client.GetAsync("api/products/1");)? The concern that I have is on the scaling aspect of the micro-services. Whenever we need the scaling, the gateway need to be scaled along with all the micro-services.

Comment: Not directly to the internals of the WebApi. I'm suggesting you create a separate project for routes and dtos. Then your WebApi micro service and your gateway uses this project. This is where you could create enums or static strings and simple DTO's that both projects could use. Then both projects are unaware of the internals, just what is exposed through this shared package.

Comment: "Magic Strings" because of the nature of URI's will exist somewhere, but you can consolidate them down into a shared package so you have a single point to edit them and the users of this package will be safe from changes.